# How to reuse a dropdown function or class on multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a great dropdown function that I picked up from w3schools and it works great except that I now need to use it on more elements(buttons). Is there a way I could reuse the function in order to accomplish this or is this a job for a class?

Here is the html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="gravatar">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
    <a href="#">Log out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.show {display:block;}
```

This is the function:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.gravatar')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Am I to assume you want to use a reusable class function?

Comment: Indeed, that would be true.

Answer (score 2):

just give the function argument when you call it

```
<div class="dropdown">
 <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown')"
 class="gravatar">Dropdown</button>
 <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
 <a href="#">Profile</a>
 <a href="#">Settings</a>
 <a href="#">Log out</a>
</div>




function myFunction(idOfTheDiv) {
    document.getElementById(idOfTheDiv).classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.gravatar')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class elToToggle {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = document.getElementById(a);
    this.b = b;
  }
  get toggle() {
    if (this.b === 'show') {

      this.a.classList.toggle('hide');

    } else {

      this.a.classList.add('hide');
    }
  }

  set outSide(outSide) {
    this.b = outSide
  }
}
var myDropDown = new elToToggle('myDropdown');
myDropDown.outSide = 'show';
myDropDown.toggle


window.onclick = function(event) {
  var start = event.target.matches('.gravatar')
  if (!start) {
    myDropDown.outSide = 'hide';
    myDropDown.toggle
    myDropDown.outSide = 'show';

  }
}
```

```css
.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myDropDown.toggle" class="gravatar">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Profile</a>
    <a href="#">Settings</a>
    <a href="#">Log out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```